# Прилагательное от слова "кино"

Tags: словообразование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, насколько литературным является слово "киношный"? И, если это разговорная форма, то как литературно образовать прилагательное от слова "кино"? Кинематографический?
Спасибо

Comment: Может быть, *михалковский*?  
![Это оно самое](http://lurkmore.so/images/thumb/c/c5/MikhalkovKlukva.jpg/200px-MikhalkovKlukva.jpg)

Comment: двусмысленная какая-то картинка. Нет?!
Особенно - в наше время.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

От слов типа метро, кино, домино и т.д. нормативные прилагательные не образуются. По регулярной парадигме должно бы быть кинный или кинной (ср. винный, сенной), но эти слова не развились в нормативные, видимо в силу молодости порождающих слов.

Отсюда и просторечно-разговорные формы типа "киношный", тоже пока не ставшие вполне нормативными. Возможно, когда-нибудь это и произойдет, тем более некоторые словари уже дают слово без помет.

А пока остается, как Вы и сказали пользоваться "заменителями" типа кинематографический.

Answer (score 2):

Слово кино имеет три значения, два из которых относятся к разговорному стилю:

КИНО, неизм.; ср.

1.Кинематография, киноискусство. Немое к. Звуковое к. Работники российского к. 2. Разг. Кинотеатр. Ходить в к. 3. Разг.Кинофильм. Какое сегодня к. идёт?

Соответственно, существует:

а) прилагательное КИНОШНЫЙ (разг.) - относящийся к кино, к кинематографии, связанный с ними. Уехать по киношным делам.

б) прилагательное (нейтр.)  КИНЕМАТОГРАФИЧЕСКИЙ (к-ая лента,  к-ая промышленность), образованный от слова КИНЕМАТОГРАФИЯ: 1. Искусство съёмки и воспроизведения на экране движущихся изображений.  2.Отрасль культуры , осуществляющая производство кинофильмов и показ их зрителю.